# How to add a key/ priority to std::priority_queue in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's Pathfinding Algorithm using the `std::priority_queue`. My Queue is of type `Node*` and I need it to prioritize based on a `float gScore` stored inside `Node` from smallest gScore to largest. I've read the documentation but I still don't understand how this can be achieved. Any ideas?

I don't understand what the type means by container_type(vector)

```
std::priority_queue<Node*> queue;
```

I greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class which will overload `()`

```
class cmp
{ 
   public:
   bool operator()(const Node *a, const Node *b) const
   {
      return (a->gscore) > (b->gscore);
   }
 };
```

Then

```
 std::priority_queue<Node*,std::vector<Node*>,cmp);
```

Comment: nice and simple explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bojangles Glad i could help.If this helped you can accept this as answer.

Comment: Should be: `bool operator()(const Node *a, const Node *b) const`

Comment: @Ajay Can you please point out why.Is it just good practice or something else.

Comment: Good practice: Yes. You clarify the intent that operator is not going to change the contents. Reason: What if `const Node*` is the type for `priority_queue`? Non-const comparison operator simply wont compile.

Comment: @Ajay Thanks a lot.

Comment: Noticed one more thing that it will reverse the PQ. You probably need to use `<` operator.

Comment: If i use `>` then the element with smallest `gscore` will have highest priority.

Comment: No. Its the other way around. Most STL containers take `std::less` for comparison and are made with `<` as default comparison. PQ will enumerate with larger to smaller one with `<`. See sample: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @GauravSehgal, Exactly that is my point. With `less`, higher value element will have higher priority (`3`). But with your custom comparator, which is `>` the element with LOWEST value gets higher priority (`1`).

Comment: Oh well, yes. You are right. I didn't see that part in question!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a comparator function. I think it would be better to implement in a manner given below , rather than declaring a class for it.

```
auto comp = [] (Node* a,Node* b) -> bool { return a->gscore < b->gscore; };
priority_queue< Node*, std::vector<Node*>, decltype(comp) > foo(comp);
```

Comment: Looks complicated but I'll give it a shot. Thank you sir

Comment: Why a reference to pointer? Lambda is not supposed to modify the Node or its contents